# jQuery chosen plugin don't search quote/apostrophe correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

When I have in select any sentence in quote/apostrophe Chosen plugin don't find that option correctly.
But if I try find sentence where quote is in middle/begining of search then all is ok.

Example:

```
<option>I write "words"</option>
```

When i try find:

```
[words] I get empty list,
["words] I get good list, 
[te "wor] I get good list.
```

I do something wrong (configuration), or this is bug/feature :P

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

Quotes was not problem. All subwords was working bad.
I should call .chosen() with parameter to search in words too.

```
.chosen({ search_contains: true });
```